# Aparecen mensajes en la terminal de VS studio Code en Mac

Tags: java, visual-studio, macos, terminal

l ejecutar mi programa me aparece este mensaje en la terminal y me parece muy molesto. ¿cómo puedo eliminar estos mensajes? en MacOs, en Visual Studio, en Xcode los elimino con system("clear"); pero aquí no puedo usar comandos del sistema, ayuda porfavor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: VS Code es un editor de código, no un IDE. Para ejecutar Java has necesitado instalar alguna extensión que lo que hace es escribir en la terminal el comando necesario para lanzar la aplicación, que es lo que estás viendo

Comment: Eso es la ejecución de tu programa `Práctica_examen_1` en la consola. Si no lo quieres ver entonces cierra el proceso que está ejecutando tu programa o detén el depurador o lo que sea que lo haya lanzado o intenta cancelarlo combinando las teclas `Command` y `C`